# Angular 7 - *ngIf on div to use class

Tags: html, angular, if-statement, angular7

I have the following `div` on my angular project:

```
<div *ngIf="isPreviewExpanded" class="project-daypart-group-columns-container-expanded pull-left">
```

Where I have two options: `isPreviewExpanded` can be true or false

if it's true I want to show it as it right now but if it's false I need to show like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!isPreviewExpanded" class="project-daypart-group-columns-container-collapsed pull-left">
```

The class changes within the value of `isPreviewExpanded`

I'm not being able to find any way to do that in the same `div`, something like:

```
<div *ngIf="isPreviewExpanded" class="project-daypart-group-columns-container-expanded; else class='project-daypart-group-columns-container-collapsed'>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use ```[ngClass]``` to set classes on your div depending on your value : ```[ngClass]="{'container-collapsed' : !isPreviewExpanded, 'container-expanded': isPreviewExpanded}"```

Comment: https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/how-to-add-a-class-based-on-condition-in-angular/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **ngClass** directive that adds and removes CSS classes on an HTML element.

```
<div class="pull-left" [ngClass]="'project-daypart-group-columns-container-expanded':isPreviewExpanded, 'project-daypart-group-columns-container-collapsed': !isPreviewExpanded>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [`NgClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).
There are multiple ways how to do it. Some ideas:

```
get dynamicClass(): string {
    return this.isPreviewExpanded ? 
        'project-daypart-group-columns-container-expanded' : 
        'project-daypart-group-columns-container-collapsed';
}

<div *ngIf="isPreviewExpanded class="pull-left' [ngClass]="dynamicClass">
```

or

```
<div
*ngIf="isPreviewExpanded"
class="pull-left"
[ngClass]="{
    'project-daypart-group-columns-container-expanded': isPreviewExpanded,
    'project-daypart-group-columns-container-collapsed': !isPreviewExpanded
}"
></div>
```